# Драйвер базы данных

Tags: golang, postgresql, sql

Какой драйвер базы данных посоветуете использовать и почему? База на postgres. В данный момент использую [go-pgsql](https://github.com/lxn/go-pgsql), но эта библиотека оказалась довольно не стабильной.

Comment: в каком смысле нестабильна?

Comment: Работает медленно на запросах, в которых извлекаются поля, содержащие много текстовых данных.

Answer (score 1):

Указанный вами в вопросе драйвер базы самый стабильный по факту. Еще есть [pq.go](https://github.com/bmizerany/pq.go), но он частично незавершен, там еще не все реализовано для database/sql, например, операция Stmp.Exec.

Answer (score 1):

Я как раз рассматриваю сейчас варианты библиотек для постгреса, можете описать чем нестабильна библиотека `https://github.com/lxn/go-pgsql` ?

Выбор, собственно, между той, что вы используете и вот этой `https://github.com/lib/pq`
У последней коммитов больше и правки были в этом году, не похожа на заброшенную.

В чём заключается нестабильность `go-pgsql` ?

Comment: @bosom, Вы на дату, когда был задан вопрос смотрите?

--

Я еще понимаю, когда Вы сообщаете (для сети знаний?), что автором Go является один из соавторов Си, но в данном-то случае -- ТС наверняка уже либо решил свою проблему, либо просто забросил эту задачу.